# Live wallpaper for android xml

Tags: android, wallpaper

Is it possible to use xml layouts in live wallpapers.  I have spent countless hours trying to code.  Have also read numerous books and logs.  But still no answer

Comment: Not being intimate with Android, a simple search turned up this http://blog.androgames.net/58/android-live-wallpaper-tutorial/ which looks to use XML as the descriptor of the service however the WallpaperService looks to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Read that blog more than once.  It is not using xml for layout.  It is using it for manifest and to declare itself as a wallpaper

Comment: What portion are you trying to remove out of _code_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A live wallpaper must do all of its drawing using the [Surface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html) and [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) APIs. You could try to inflate some Views from XML and [draw()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) them to a Canvas but it's probably more trouble than it's worth.